# Passing data to other activity without opening it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass the data from one activity to another activity without opening the activity. I tried it by not writing **startActivity(intent)** part but it fails.

How do I pass the data from one activity(1) to another activity(2) **without opening that activity(2)**?

Comment: You could pass data to a SharedPreferences then recover it on activity 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: I dont think that there is a need to pass data to another activity if you are not showing it at that moment of time...You should either save data in a file and load it when activity opens next time or you should use database.

Answer (score 2):

Activities are UI elements so your question makes no sense. If you want perform some action that does not have UI create a service to perform the work and start or otherwise call that service from your first activity.

If you want to make data available to activity 2 when it does start, pick a persistent storage mechanism and write the data there, then read the data when activity 2 opens.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Alternatively, you can create a custom `Application` and store the data there and share it between activities.

Just a word of advice. You should describe what you are trying to accomplish not how you want to accomplish it. Activities are not the right tool for this task, but we can't suggest the right tool because we don't know what you want to build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events for passing around data. Either use the android native LocalBroadcastsSytem and put data as parcelable in the intent, or you can use any event library like EventBus

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data from one activity to another activity without opening the activity try to do with the broadcast receiver or SharePhreferance or make that data public static You can access your data in anywhere of the application.